# Activiti: Adding task local variables adhoc

Tags: activiti

I have to change process definition, as a result of which a user task would now have 2 new local variables.

But it is interfering with those tasks which are already in the system, and hence don't have those 2 new variables.

I have 2 options here:

1. Either I modify java code somehow to handle this.

OR

2. Before deploying new process definition, modify java code so that when a user logs in the system, those 2 variables are added to the task assigned to her task.(or it may also be done by running a script to update respective activiti tables).

But I am not sure which one would be a preferable approach?

Input would be really helpful.

Edit:

For eg., a usecase is to find assigned task. In current implementation, it simply is as:

```
taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(userId).singleResult()
```

It works because at a time there can be only one task assigned to user.

Now,in new requirement there can be multiple tasks assigned, one of which user is currently working on. So I make use of 2 new task variables like this:

```
Task currentTask = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(userId)
            .taskVariableValueEquals("current", true).singleResult();
    if(currentTask == null){
        List<Task> unsuspendedTasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(userId)
                .taskVariableValueEquals("suspended", false).list();

        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(tasksAssignedToUser)) {
            sortTasksBasedOnPriorityAndCreateTime(tasksAssignedToUser);
            currentTask = tasksAssignedToUser.get(tasksAssignedToUser.size() - 1);

        }
    }
```

So, we first query for task which has variable "current" set as true. If no such task is there, then we query for tasks which have variable "suspended" set as false, and we sort those tasks, and pick up first one.

But for tasks already existing, these two variables, "current" and "suspended", won't be available.

Comment: how are they interfering? most probable cause would be in your custom logic. more information in needed.

Comment: @AbbasKararawala, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to modify your existing custom code for a new process definition. if your code if tightly coupled with your process - as you described regarding the task variables. I recommend you create another bean for your new process. this way you'll be able to work with your new process without affecting the logic of old one.